# How do I convert a JSON file to a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I apologize for the large JSON file. I want to be able to create a csv file that extracts each link (under embedLink), the tags, and the rank. However, each of my attempts have come up short. This is the code that I currently have; however, it outputs multiple errors.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

import json, csv

x="""{u'results': [{u'index': 4367, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/MazO89pt5NljG/giphy.gif', u'tags': [u'dance', 
u'silly', u'carlton', u'banks', u'fresh prince'], u'added_with_admin': True, 
u'dateAdded': 1394519920.03, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/MazO89pt5NljG/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 38.367645789902205, u'sigma': 2.184739493694442}, u'cID': 
u'f10e5808d396e2e4ba0ab48c', u'rank': 0, u'content': u'MazO89pt5NljG', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 370, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media1.giphy.com/media/HscrwGNPHio2A/giphy.gif', u'tags': 
[u'excitedexcited', u'jeremy renner'], u'added_with_admin': False, 
u'dateAdded': 1393863494.644655, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/HscrwGNPHio2A/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 37.24778379219212, u'sigma': 1.5847716442668915}, u'cID': 
u'5314ab46d34b6c5b402aeb39', u'rank': 1, u'content': u'HscrwGNPHio2A', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 287, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media2.giphy.com/media/CCJnMBqEYxxEk/giphy.gif', u'tags': [u'tv', 
u'happy', u'30 rock', u'tina fey', u'high five', u'liz lemon', 
u'celebration'], u'added_with_admin': False, u'dateAdded': 
1393863490.821621, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/CCJnMBqEYxxEk/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 36.59521670234331, u'sigma': 1.681281739841269}, u'cID': 
u'5314ab42d34b6c5b402aeae6', u'rank': 2, u'content': u'CCJnMBqEYxxEk', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 2681, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/Mn0C1r0qL7XWg/giphy.gif', u'tags': [u'funny', 
u'happy', u'excited', u'crazy'], u'added_with_admin': True, u'dateAdded': 
1394378341.692, u'still_image': u 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/Mn0C1r0qL7XWg/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 36.56837392887614, u'sigma': 1.6136408794819588}, u'cID': 
u'3844637f65451dffd3698425', u'rank': 3, u'content': u'Mn0C1r0qL7XWg', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 247, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/AAXjZcPFzTPO/giphy.gif', u'tags': [u'smile', 
u'happy', u'laughing', u'black', u'hipster', u'beautiful girls', u'be 
happy', u'pixie cut'], u'added_with_admin': False, u'dateAdded': 
1393863489.035277, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/AAXjZcPFzTPO/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 36.34056334299456, u'sigma': 1.7996651935876014}, u'cID': 
u'5314ab41d34b6c5b402aeabe', u'rank': 4, u'content': u'AAXjZcPFzTPO', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 1429, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/7SQtrK5JbFTFK/giphy.gif', u'tags': 
[u'cartoons & comics', u'dancing', u'the simpsons', u'friday', u'lisa 
simpson', u'tgif'], u'added_with_admin': False, u'dateAdded': 
1394091573.355619, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/7SQtrK5JbFTFK/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 36.2797522468539, u'sigma': 1.3927800299100415}, u'cID': 
u'53182635d34b6c1910c00332', u'rank': 5, u'content': u'7SQtrK5JbFTFK', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 2749, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media2.giphy.com/media/wRGJgKQdpagFO/giphy.gif', u'tags': 
[u'dancing', u'happy', u'jimmy fallon', u'jimmy fallon'], 
u'added_with_admin': True, u'dateAdded': 1394386054.159, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/wRGJgKQdpagFO/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 36.14775637052213, u'sigma': 1.365824510294118}, u'cID': 
u'010e4981a9a97e6a007d8a65', u'rank': 6, u'content': u'wRGJgKQdpagFO', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 12, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': u 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/10UeedrT5MIfPG/giphy.gif', u'tags': 
[u'dancing', u'giphytrending', u'happy', u'cartoons', u'giphytv', u'tom and 
jerry'], u'added_with_admin': False, u'dateAdded': 1393863477.161998, 
u'still_image': u'http://media.giphy.com/media/10UeedrT5MIfPG/200_s.gif'}, 
u'parameters': {u'mu': 36.09150478133458, u'sigma': 1.4215081662482691}, 
u'cID': u'5314ab35d34b6c5b402ae9d3', u'rank': 7, u'content': 
u'10UeedrT5MIfPG', u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 1624, 
u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/h8UyZ6FiT0ptC/giphy.gif', u'tags': 
[u'dancing', u'happy', u'birthday', u'fat', u't', u'giphybirthday', u'happy 
dance', u'taco bell', u'junk food', u'oh yea', u't card'], 
u'added_with_admin': False, u'dateAdded': 1394091596.424046, u'still_image': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/h8UyZ6FiT0ptC/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 35.96712787907767, u'sigma': 1.4742260856412648}, u'cID': 
u'5318264cd34b6c1910c003f5', u'rank': 8, u'content': u'h8UyZ6FiT0ptC', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}, {u'index': 193, u'content_data': {u'embedLink': 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/6onMzNPjtFeCI/giphy.gif', u'tags': 
[u'laughing', u'excited', u'minions'], u'added_with_admin': False, 
u'dateAdded': 1393863486.381926, u'still_image': u 
u'http://media.giphy.com/media/6onMzNPjtFeCI/200_s.gif'}, u'parameters': 
{u'mu': 35.77139953100954, u'sigma': 1.3739202465218552}, u'cID': 
u'5314ab3ed34b6c5b402aea88', u'rank': 9, u'content': u'6onMzNPjtFeCI', 
u'content_type': u'gif'}], u'query_parameters': {u'sort': 1, u'skip': 0, 
u'limit': 10, u'mID': u'54a309ae1c61be23aba0da5c'}}
"""

x = json.loads(x)

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))

f.writerow(["results", "index"])

for row in x:
   f.writerow( [row['results'], row['index']] )
```

Example desired output:

```
0, dance, silly, carlton, banks, fresh prince, media.giphy.com/media/MazO89pt5NljG/giphy.gif
1, excitedexcited, jeremy renner, media1.giphy.com/media/HscrwGNPHio2A/giphy.gif
2, tv, happy, 30 rock, tina fey, high five, liz lemon, celebration, media2.giphy.com/media/CCJnMBqEYxxEk/giphy.gif
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I've been working on this for a long time and it's been stumping me. If you have any possible solution to my problem, let me know. I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: Please add an example of what the output CSV should look like.

Comment: 0 , dance, silly, carlton, banks, fresh prince, http://media.giphy.com/media/MazO89pt5NljG/giphy.gif
1, excitedexcited, jeremy renner, http://media1.giphy.com/media/HscrwGNPHio2A/giphy.gif
2, tv, happy, 30 rock, tina fey, high five, liz lemon, celebration, http://media2.giphy.com/media/CCJnMBqEYxxEk/giphy.gif

Comment: Sorry, the links kind of screwed it up. The numbers (0, 1, 2) should be on a separate line

Comment: I edited your question; is that what the output should look like?  (Please try editing it yourself.)

Comment: Yes that is what it should look like. Sorry, this is my first time here.

Answer (score 2):

You may use pandas and convert .json first in Dataframe and later in .csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('filename.json')
df.to_csv(filename.csv)
```

Comment: I've never used pandas before, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @P.Nar Pandas is inbuilt library now in Python and very powerful tool for data analytic works, and can very well serve the purpose of changing formats to xls, csv, json html, fwf etc. If your work get done by my code,  please tick mark this answer to show verified. Thanks